# How to log the inputs made by the user in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form with a textarea input field. The primary objective is to strip down all the characters other than alphabets and digits from the input text and return the results in a div. I accomplish that with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#input').keyup(function () {
        var value = $('#input').val();
        var replaced = value.replace(/[^\da-z]/gi, '').toLowerCase();
        $('#output').val(replaced);
    });
});
```

All of this works perfectly, and the results are updated real time as the user enters the input text. What I want to do is to log the input text *after* the user has entered the input text.

I'm performing the logging by sending the input text to a PHP script using `$.get`. So if I perform the GET inside the `.keyup(function () { ... }` block, it will send a GET request for each and every character entered.

For example, if the input is `hello`, then the logging will be peformed as follows:

```
h
he
hel
hell
hello
```

I only need the last part to be logged.  I was thinking to perform the logging every X seconds and have the PHP script check if the input is valid. I'm new to programming, so I'm not sure how to do this.

What's a good way to accomplish this? I'm not looking for code to copy paste, so just the suggestion/approach is fine too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the blur event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#input').keyup(function () {
        var value = $('#input').val();
        var replaced = value.replace(/[^\da-z]/gi, '').toLowerCase();
        $('#output').val(replaced);
    });
    $('#input').blur(function(){
        //send data
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/blur/